# Recovery of deleted folders in home folder

Tags: home-directory, folder, delete

By accident I've removed some folders (they were empty) in my home folder. I've created a new ones but they doesn't have proper icons etc... how can I recreate them step by step?

Comment: Instead of creating folders, just logout/login.

Comment: Systemfiles in your home get recreated if they are missing when you start a new login! So remove the files you added yourself.

Comment: unfortunately didn't help...I removed my icons, but the new ones didn,t appear...after relogin and even after restart

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, to restore deleted directories

edit `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` ,

```
gedit ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs
```

it should look like this:

```
# This file is written by xdg-user-dirs-update
# If you want to change or add directories, just edit the line you're
# interested in. All local changes will be retained on the next run
# Format is XDG_xxx_DIR="$HOME/yyy", where yyy is a shell-escaped
# homedir-relative path, or XDG_xxx_DIR="/yyy", where /yyy is an
# absolute path. No other format is supported.
# 
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Public"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documents"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/Music"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"
```

If that fails, install and run Ubuntu Tweak

http://ubuntu-tweak.com/

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: Absolutely Perfect.

Comment: This helped me greatly. I mistakenly deleted, and restoring did the trick. Thank you sir!

Answer (score 0):

First, stop using your system from the hard drive ASAP. You will need to boot a live CD and try recovery from there.

I have had mixed, generally poor results with the ext4 file system, but try , in order, testdisk and then photorec. Both are in the repositories and both can be installed in the live session

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install testdisk
```

You then run testdisk from the command line

```
# you might be able to run it as a user, but I would run it as root
sudo testdisk
```

There is a step-by-step tutorial , with screen shots, here

http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk:_undelete_file_for_ext2

If that fails, try photorec.

Photorec is a part of the testdisk package, again there is a detailed walk through here

http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec_Step_By_Step

If that fails, you can try extundelete

http://extundelete.sourceforge.net/

Last time I tried that, it did not recover my files.

Good luck.

Comment: Well I don't want to recover any files because they didn't exist in  my folders. Folders were empty. I just want to recreate home folders like images, videos etc...

Comment: What directories (folders) ?

Comment: When You open Your home folder You can see folders like Documents, Images, Videos etc... and I mean these folders. I've deleted them and I want to recreate them with proper icons for each.

Comment: I added an answer, I thought from my read you were in the data recovery mode , sorry

Comment: The first method didn't worked, terminal gave me some errors about missing files during saving user-dirs.dirs, but ubuntu tweak worked. Thank You!