# How to change file into folder?

Tags: files, directory

My folder Desktop changed to file Desktop (without extension, 6MB).
How can I turn it back? I need that content.

Comment: How did the folder change into a file?

Comment: Better link - http://askubuntu.com/questions/86982/recovery-of-deleted-folders-in-home-folder

Comment: @Jobin The "Desktop" directory , and other, have special definitions, see my links

Comment: @bodhi.zazen: But will that restore the data that the OP is talking about?

Comment: @bodhi.zahen: Ubuntu-tweak restored my directory, but it is empty - and the Desktop file is gone. Fortunately I've copied it. My question is actual.

Comment: No, Data recovery is a different animal. See - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery

Comment: @Jobin: I copied .jpg from sd card to desktop, I tried to open it, image viewer errored, desktop cleared itself. I didn't check if there was Desktop file at the moment.
After system restart there was Desktop file for sure.